# function that runs when dynamically generated control is interacted with

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, datagridview, controls

I've been Having trouble with making a sub that runs when my datagridview cell is doubleclicked. It is caused because the datagridview is programmatically created, rather than created by the designer. I have found a help website i will include that appears to be related to the issue.

```
Public Class seattemplatecreator
    Dim alphabet() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
    Private WithEvents dgv_flightTemplate As DataGridView

    'help from https://it.toolbox.com/question/event-for-dynamically-created-command-button-043008

    Public Sub init(ByVal dgv01 As DataGridView)
        dgv_flightTemplate = dgv01
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgv_flightTemplate_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgv_flightTemplate.CellMouseDoubleClick
        MsgBox("workwd")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_createflight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_createflight.Click
        'used https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e222f438-f060-4e61-ab28-523d02db91b2/how-to-programmatically-create-datagridview-with-empty-columns-and-rows?forum=vbgeneral
        'to help with this part for automatically generating the datagridview

        MsgBox(alphabet(0))

        Dim dgv_flightTemplate As New DataGridView
        Dim c As Integer = txb_columns.Text
        Dim r As Integer = txb_rows.Text

        For colcount As Integer = 0 To c - 1
            Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            nc.Name = "Seating Column"
            dgv_flightTemplate.Columns.Add(nc)
        Next
        dgv_flightTemplate.Rows.Add(r)

        For x = 0 To r - 1
            dgv_flightTemplate.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value = alphabet(x).ToString
        Next

        Me.Controls.Add(dgv_flightTemplate)
        dgv_flightTemplate.Location = New Point(400, 400)
        dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        dgv_flightTemplate.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

        dgv_flightTemplate.AutoResizeRows()
        dgv_flightTemplate.AutoSize = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

https://it.toolbox.com/question/event-for-dynamically-created-command-button-043008

Edit: Olivier Jacot-Descombes response was perfect all that was needed was run the "Init" sub.
    Public Class seattemplatecreator

```
Dim alphabet() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
Private WithEvents dgv_flightTemplate As DataGridView
'help from https://it.toolbox.com/question/event-for-dynamically-created-command-button-043008
Public Sub init(ByVal dgv01 As DataGridView)
    dgv_flightTemplate = dgv01
End Sub
Private Sub dgv_flightTemplate_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgv_flightTemplate.CellMouseDoubleClick
    MsgBox("workwd")
End Sub

Private Sub btn_createflight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_createflight.Click

    'used https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e222f438-f060-4e61-ab28-523d02db91b2/how-to-programmatically-create-datagridview-with-empty-columns-and-rows?forum=vbgeneral 
    'to help with this part for automatically generating the datagridview
    MsgBox(alphabet(0))
    Dim dgv_flightTemplate As New DataGridView
    Dim c As Integer = txb_columns.Text
    Dim r As Integer = txb_rows.Text
    For colcount As Integer = 0 To c - 1
        Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        nc.Name = "Seating Column"
        dgv_flightTemplate.Columns.Add(nc)
    Next
    dgv_flightTemplate.Rows.Add(r)
    For x = 0 To r - 1
        dgv_flightTemplate.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value = alphabet(x).ToString

    Next
    Me.Controls.Add(dgv_flightTemplate)


    dgv_flightTemplate.Location = New Point(400, 400)
    dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dgv_flightTemplate.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    dgv_flightTemplate.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders

    dgv_flightTemplate.AutoResizeRows()
    dgv_flightTemplate.AutoSize = True

    init(dgv_flightTemplate)






End Sub





End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, Taine

Comment: The event handler is no different whether you create the control in the designer or in code.  The only difference is that you must use an `AddHandler` statement to register the event handler rather than a `Handles` clause on the method declaration.

Comment: Where does `btn_createflight` come from. Is this the form code? I am missing `Inherits Form`.

Comment: btn_createflight is a button on the form that creates the datagridview with the number of columns and number of rows set out by two textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `Init`. But instead, you could as well directly assign to the field

```
dgv_flightTemplate = New DataGridView 'Note: No Dim here.
```

But even if you are creating the columns dynamically, you could add a grid with the designer. Just call

```
dgv_flightTemplate.Columns.Clear()
```

before adding columns.

Comment: thanks for your help! the other methods are also good but it was as simple as using the init sub